# Alternative to Control-D for paste mode in scala repl?

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

I would like to simply paste in code as follows

```
:paste
<your code here>
--   // or something .. not sure what this were..
```

The dashes comes from ipython.. Is Control-D the only option here?

Comment: what is the problem you try to avoid ?

Comment: @rotari Hitting control-D is not a preferred approach: one cannot put "CTRL-D" into a string.  Since the code is pasted repetitively from a real editor, I want to copy the segment of code into repl and have the evaluation occur immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might create an issue around alternative paste terminators.

How about here doc syntax?

```
scala> :paste <--
[paste here]
--
```

Comment: or just -- like in python?  Seems you were suggesting here that CTL-D is all we have. Given your depth in scala i will accept that at face value.

Comment: In fact I'm not sure how to get ctl-d into the paste buffer. The problem with special-casing `--` is that it is a valid Scala identifier. https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9492

Comment: Thx for creating that!

Answer (score 2):

There is an alternative REPL - [Ammonite](https://lihaoyi.github.io/Ammonite/), which allow paste bloxk by using

```
{{ 
<paste> 
}}
```